# Regex for matching certain numbers of digits

Tags: regex, validation

The following regex will match the range 9-11 digits: `/\d{9,11}/`

What is the best way to write a regex matching exactly 9 *or* 11 digits (excluding 10)?

Using the pattern attribute of an input element, thus the regex should match the entire value of the input field. I want to accept any number containing 9 or 11 digits.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you do not want to match *at all* 9 digits within a larger group of digits?  That you want to find lines which specifically contain a 9-digit number or an 11-digit number?  Also, can there be other content in the line?  Some of the people answering your question are clearly confused about this and I may have made wrong assumptions.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you made clear which tool or language you are working with, as exact syntax differs.

Comment: I've included info about which context I want to use the regex in in the question text.

Comment: I have a Gist on this https://gist.github.com/SHi-ON/b2ae4100f50b2e2d96ff8277632cc325

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, you could try something like:

```
^\d{9}(\d{2})?$
```

This matches exactly nine digits followed by an optional extra-two-digits (i.e., 9 or 11 digits).

Alternatively,

```
^(\d{9}|\d{11})$
```

may work as well.

But remember that not *everything* necessarily has to be done with regular expressions. It may be just as easy to check the string matches `^\d*$` and that the string length itself is either 9 or 11 (using something like `strlen`, for example).

Comment: Thanks, I want to use this in the pattern attribute of an input, so I'd prefer to use a single regex.

Comment: You will match 9 digits within 10 (or more) or 11 digits within 12 or more.  I do not think this is what the OP wants (though I may be wrong).

Comment: @Jørgen, then use the first regex I gave. It will work fine, depending on your regex engine (which is relatively modern since it supports `\d`).

Comment: @itsbruce, no, the anchors take care of that - it's either exactly nine or exactly nine followed by exactly two.

Comment: OK, now that the OP has clarified that anchors are implicit in any case, I have no objection ;)

Answer (score 7):

This regex would do

```
^(\d{9}|\d{11})$
```

or if you dont want to match it exactly

```
\D(\d{9}|\d{11})\D
```

Comment: That will match a line only containing 9 or 11 digits and absolutely nothing else.  Did the OP specify there should be nothing else in the line?

Comment: @itsbruce he said **exactly** in his question

Comment: He said he wanted to match exactly that many digits.  He didn't say they should be the only things on the line.  You have made an unwarranted assumption.  Maybe that's what the OP wanted (I've asked for clarification) but it's not specified.

Comment: Well, to be fair, the OP has now clarified what he wanted.  I was just being pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

```
/[^\d](\d{9}|\d{11})[^\d]/
```

Depending on which tool you are using, you may need to escape the *(*, *|* and *)* characters.

Note that in order to not match 8, or any other number other than 9 or 11, the regex must be bounded with something to indicate that the match is surrounded by non-digit characters.  Ideally, it would be some kind of word-boundary character, but the syntax for that would vary depending on the tool.

```
/\b(\d{9}|\d{11})\b/
```

works with some tools.  What are you working with?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the regex in the pattern attribute of an input element, so it will automatically be limited with ^ and $