# Php search for a pattern in a string

Tags: php, regex, search

Can someone help me to find the job id from the text below:

```
$search_string = '/jobs/17 has no compatible crew with sufficient capacity (job: 304390)';
```

I have tried the following but did not have any luck:

```
preg_match("/\[job: ([A-Za-z\/]+)\]/", $search_string, $match);
print_r($match) --showing empty
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for matching certain numbers of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178912/regex-for-matching-certain-numbers-of-digits)

Comment: Why do you have `\[` and `\]`? There don't appear to be any `[]`s in your string.  Also `[A-Za-z\/]` would look for alpha characters or a backslash, what do you want to match, the `17`, the `30`, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should match parenthesis instead, and capture 1 or more digits. Then you can get the group 1 value:

```
\(job: (\d+)\)/
```

Example

```
$search_string = '/jobs/17 has no compatible crew with sufficient capacity (job: 304390)';
if (preg_match("/\(job: (\d+)\)/", $search_string, $match)) {
    print_r($match[1]);
}
```

Output

```
304390
```